# Finding elements in beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i need to get the user from the a element and i have no idea how  "last line in pic"
[PRESS TO SEE THE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBaMX.png)

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml



class Scraper:

    def hastags_these(self, *hashtags):
        self.hashtag_list = []

        for hashtag in hashtags:
            self.hashtag_list.append(hashtag)
        print(self.hashtag_list)

    def get_hashtag_page(self):
        i = len(self.hashtag_list)
        lit = []
        for i in self.hashtag_list:
            self.page = requests.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{self.hashtag_list[0]}/').text
            self.html_page = self.page
            self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.html_page, 'html.parser')
            self.user = self.soup.select("body > div._2dDPU.CkGkG > div.zZYga > div > article > header > div.o-MQd > div.PQo_0 > div.e1e1d > span > a")




Scrap = Scraper()
Scrap.hastags_these('freelancer', 'python', 'java')
Scrap.get_hashtag_page()
```

what i am trying to do is search for users using one of these hashtags, the only remaning part is the username and idk how to do it

Comment: Do not post images as code. paste the HTML here. What have you tried so far? please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: all what i have done is opening the page with requests, all i need now is to get the username inside the <a> tag

Comment: Please share the URL / HTML and that you have already tried

Comment: *body > div._2dDPU.CkGkG > div.zZYga > div > article > header > div.o-MQd > div.PQo_0 > div.e1e1d > span > a"   --this is the css selector of the tag i want

Comment: but when i put in the code, it returns None

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/freelancer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understood, that you try to get something from that `a tag` what seems to be the username `yunsx` (as mentioned in the comments, it would be helpful to get more details)

**Minimal Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc ='''
<div class="e1e1d">
    <span class="some-class"</span>
        <a class="some-class" href="/yunsx/">
            yunsx
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

Get the `a tag`

```
userHref = soup.select('div.e1e1d > span > a')
```

Print results of `attrs['href']` and its `text.strip()`:

```
print('a href:'+userHref[0].attrs['href'])
print('a text:'+userHref[0].text.strip())
```

**Output**

```
a href:/yunsx/
a text:yunsx
```